# Example of Angular mat-tree with icons

Tags: tree, angular-material

Does somebody have an example of mat-tree with icons and a datasource that comes from a service? An example on Stackblitz would be great.

Answer (score 6):

Using https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-mat-tree-test, I created https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-mat-tree-test-7 which also has icons.

It is now also on github: https://github.com/pappasa/ng-mat-tree-test.
You can open it on stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/github/pappasa/ng-mat-tree-test

Comment: Thank you Alex. Very useful answer :)